# resolver on lazy loading angular

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-resolver

is there a way to add a resolver before loading a lazy load module? i tried to add `resolve` to the routs configuration but it is not triggered, also didn't find any thing useful about it on the web. any help would be appreciated

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
// services
import {SecondResolverService} from "./second.resolver.service";

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'first' , loadChildren: './first/first.module#FirstModule' },
  { path: 'second', loadChildren: './second/second.module#SecondModule' ,resolve : {data : SecondResolverService}}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: What do you main about "before loading a lazy load module"? I have implemented routing like that and it works, when the navigation finish I got the data requested.

Comment: do you use a resolve in your routing?

Comment: Yes, I do. The only difference is that I do it in a child module not in app module. So I have appmodule -> ChildOneModule -> ChildTwoModule, and in the routing of the ChildOneModule I have a resolver when resolving a path to ChildTwoModule and I have the data in all routes of ChildTwoModule...

The only difference is that i don't export the RouterModule, I just import it like you do (in child I use forChild insted of forRoot but is the same) and I import in my AppModule the AppRoutingModule

Comment: nope, don't think so. you can add a resolver to the eager route immediately *before* the lazy loaded route

Comment: @pixelbits - it doesn't make sense if it is resolver is required for `Feature Module` which is lazy module then why resolver should be declared in `Eager Module`.

Comment: That’s just the way it is

Comment: @omer did you figure this out ?

Comment: Yes I did will upload my solution in a few hours

Comment: I didn’t figure it out I have half a solution that’s way I didn’t post yet..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Angular docs on lazy loading](https://angular.io/guide/router#lazy-loading-route-configuration)

This config always works for me.
If this doesnt work there may be something wrong with your resolver.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'second',
    loadChildren: () => import('/second/second.module')
      .then(m => m.SecondModule),
    resolve: {
      data: SecondResolverService
    }
  },
```

Comment: the whole "something wrong with your resolver" is what saved me here, got me to look closer at mine which was in fact the problem

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same issue. Here is an example of this issue in Stackblitz.com in Angular 9

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ubes1q?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

The ChildResolver is set on the lazy-loaded route, but never gets called.

---

My workaround was to make a "lazyResolver" inside my guard.

So something like this in `data.guard.ts`:

```
export class MyGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild {

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private myService: MyService,
  ) { }

  public canActivate(route, state): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> {
    return this.lazyResolver$().pipe(
      map(data => {
        // now we lazy resolved!
        return true;
      }),
      take(1),
      catchError(error => EMPTY),
    );
  }

  // safeguard when using resolvers and guards with lazy-loaded modules
  private lazyResolver$(): Observable<any> {
    return new MyResolver(this.myService).resolve(route, state),
  );
```

}

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, as they are rendered useless if the link stops working or the content significantly changes. You should [edit] your answer to include the most important details that are relevant to the question in the answer itself. Answers that are little more than a link somewhere else may end up being [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Updated my comment with example workaround. Thanks.

Comment: I created an issue in github for this, maybe others in the Angular world can shine a light on this issue or non-issue.
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/37625